# Avoid using the default edit form with Material-React-Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-react-table

In the following Material-React-Table code that I extracted from an example, a default form is used to edit the record, but it doesn't work for me because I need to be able to create my own.
Could you give me a guide on how to create it and pass it the registration data?

```
          renderRowActions={({ row, table }) => (
            <Stack direction="row" >
            <Tooltip title={('Edit')} >
              <IconButton onClick={() => table.setEditingRow( row )} >
                <EditOutlinedIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            <Tooltip title={('Delete')} > 
              <IconButton onClick={(event) => handleDeleteClick(event, row)} >
              <DeleteOutlineIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </Tooltip>
            </Stack>
          )}
```

Thanks in advance.

I don't realize how to do it and I hope you can help me to solve it.